# how to determine sets of polynomials linearly independent in $P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

For example, in the case of  $${\{x^2,(x-5)^2, x-2}\}$$ What I know is that, this is not top-down basis because of $(t-2)^2$ is missing.
I don't know how to determine if it is linearly independent or not.

Comment: I doubt I tagged right words :(

Comment: Independence was the only wrong one- that's a probabilistic notion.

Comment: Thanks for your correction sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach here would be to try to represent one of your three basis vectors as a linear combination of the other two, or show why that's impossible. If it's possible, there's linearly dependent, and if not, they're linearly independent. Since there are only three vectors, this is fairly easy.

Say $(x-5)^2$, which is equal to $x^2-10x+25$, can be represented as the linear combination $x^2-10x+25=ax^2+b(x-2)$ where $a$ and $b$ are some scalars (I assume real, though that doesn't matter). Clearly, $a=1$; you need the coefficient of $x^2$ to be $1$, and $x^2$ appears only once on the right hand side, so it must have coefficient $1$ there. Then, if this linear combination is possible, what is $b$? You can either find a value for $b$ such that this works, or show that no such $b$ exists.

Comment: Then as you said, a=1 and b should be -10 which makes constant as 20. In this case, 20 and 25 are not the same, so these are not linearly independent right?

Comment: Close, but other way around. If you $\textit{can't}$ represent one as a linear combination of the other two, then they $\textit{are}$ linearly independent.

Comment: Oh oh, I got this, so they are not represented by each other, so they $are$ linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

The functions are linearly independent if and only if  ...

The only solutions for a,b, and c that satisfy the identity ...
$$ax^2+b(x-5)^2+c(x-2)=0 $$

are $a=b=c=0$

In your case you have

$$ (a+b)x^2+(-10b+c)x+(25b-2c) =0  $$

so you need to solve the system

$$a+b=0; -10b+c=0; 25b-2c=0  $$

the first equation gives $a = -b$

the second equation gives $c=10b$

plugging this into the third equations gives $25b-20b=0$

so we must have $b=0$  which can be plugged into the other 2 equations to give $ c=0$ and $a=0$

So these functions are linearly independent

Comment: I'm not sure but in case of b=0 and if one of a or c become not 0, then is it also linearly independent? Like just in case, if $a!=0$, b=0, c=0 and variables of $x^2$, x, 1 are 0, then is it linearly independent?

Comment: @Tot What do you mean by "variables of $x^2, x, 1$ are $0$"? Do you mean their coefficients? A set of vectors being linearly independent means, by definition, that there is no nontrivial representation of the zero vector using a linear representation of the set (trivial means the zero representation). So if you had vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and you had $av_1+bv_2+cv_3=0$ and $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$ or $c\neq 0$ (at least one nonzero, potentially all), then that set of vectors would not be linearly independent.